# Automapper map predefined value in .net

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, mapping, automapper

I am trying to map string value fields from MongoDB to integers in VisualStudio, using .NET. The fields have one of a few known values, like "pedestrian", "bicycle", "car". How can i check against these values and map them to be represented by "0", "1", "2"? I know the basics of automapper, but i cant find how to do this.
I am getting them as a List<> and they need to stay as a List<>.

Using:

- VS 19
- Automapper v8

Example of a MongoDB document:

```
{
  "Street" : "Oak",
  "Object" : "pedestrian",
  "Id" : "046b6c7f-0b8a-43b9-b35d-6489e6daee91",
  "City" : "NY",
  "Direction" : 0
}
```

Comment: Value converter should work for you https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Value-converters.html

Comment: If you can use a POCO with an enum, where "object" is say an enum with pedestrian, car, etc. then you can use `.ForMember(d => d.MyIntegerProp, op => op.MapFrom(o => o.CustomObject))`. I'd also recommend changing the property name "object" to something that isn't a keyword in most languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the rows:

```
public class Stuff
{
    [BsonElement("_id")]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public List<MyDocument> MyDocuments { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
var client = new MongoClient();
var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = database.GetCollection<Stuff>("alma");
var rows = (await collection.FindAsync(FilterDefinition<Stuff>.Empty)).ToList();
```

### Option 1:

You don't need to use Automapper for that, the MongoDB driver converts enums as long as the name of the option matches.

```
[BsonNoId]
public class MyDocument
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public ObjectEnum Object { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Direction { get; set; }
}

public enum ObjectEnum
{
    None = 0,
    pedestrian = 1,
    bicycle = 2,
    car = 3
}
```

...

```
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    // use the enum, or if you need the associated number just use int cast
    int myNumberRepresentation = (int)row.MyDocuments[0].Object;
}
```

### Option 2:

Write custom serializer, and your return type can be anything you like:

```
public enum ObjectEnum
{
    None = 0,
    // notice the upper case
    Pedestrian = 1,
    Bicycle = 2,
    Car = 3
}

[BsonNoId]
public class MyDocument
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    [BsonSerializer(typeof(CustomObjectSerializer))]
    public ObjectEnum Object { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Direction { get; set; }
}

public class CustomObjectSerializer: SerializerBase<ObjectEnum>
{
    public override ObjectEnum Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        var s = context.Reader.ReadString();
        switch (s)
        {
            case "pedestrian":
                return ObjectEnum.Pedestrian;
            case "bicycle":
                return ObjectEnum.Bicycle;
            case "car":
                return ObjectEnum.Car;
            default:
                return ObjectEnum.None;
        }
    }

    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, ObjectEnum value)
    {
        string ret = "";
        switch (value)
        {
            case ObjectEnum.Pedestrian:
                ret = "pedestrian";
                break;
            case ObjectEnum.Bicycle:
                ret = "bicycle";
                break;
            case ObjectEnum.Car:
                ret = "car";
                break;
        }
        context.Writer.WriteString(ret);
    }
}
```